# How to change the value of a column "Modified By" of a Sharepoint List with Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have this code below but it doesn't work. Is it possible to change a value of the column "Modified By" in a Sharepoint list with Powershell?

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "mylist" -Identity "1" -Values @{"Editor" = "kees@apg.nl"}
```

Gr. P

Comment: It won't be that simple. The Editor field is a complex object, not just a text string with the email address.

Comment: Oke I think i will try another way. I saw an article about Microsoft Flow. Thanks for the info.Gr. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "Demo List" -Identity 1 -Values @{"Editor"="testuser@domain.com"} -UpdateType UpdateOverwriteVersion
```

`-UpdateType`
Specifies the update type to use when updating the list item. Possible values are "Update", "SystemUpdate", "UpdateOverwriteVersion".

`Update`: Sets field values and creates a new version if versioning is enabled for the list

`SystemUpdate`: Sets field values and does not create a new version. Any events on the list will trigger.

`UpdateOverwriteVersion`: Sets field values and does not create a new version. No events on the list will trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Please use /validateUpdateListItem for updating Modified By field in the Flow:

[image]

[modifying Modified By and Modified time with Microsoft Flow](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow)

Comment: Can not find compose user in power automate

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: It's just the same "Compose" action, in the demo above, it's renamed to "Compose User" for a better understanding